# Best way to persist an entity of unknown type using JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

I'm working on a spring boot application containing a set of JPA entities. Some of the entities are unique to the application, but a subset are retrieved from an independent REST server.

The application listens for JMS messages, and, upon their receipt, makes a REST call to the server to retrieve an XML payload, which it then unmarshals into an object for use in some business logic. The entities need to be persisted to a (PostgresQL) database upon receipt, and retrieved at certain points in certain classes.

However, the Xml marshalling is performed without any knowledge of the payload type, and I was wondering if there is some analogue for persisting an entity using a JpaRepository, without type-checking and creating a repository using a factory.

Currently the most appropriate solution I can think of is to have a JpaRepositoryFactory which returns the appropriate repository, as below:

```
@Component
public class JpaRepositoryFactory {

    @Autowired
    FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Autowired
    BarRepository barRepository;

    @Autowired
    BazRepository bazRepository;

    public static JpaRepository retrieveRepository(Class clazz) {
        switch (clazz) {
            case Foo.class:
                return fooRepository;
                break;
            case Bar.class:
                return barRepository;
                break;
            case Baz.class;
                return bazRepository;
                break;
            default:
                throw SomeJpaRepositoryFactoryException();
        }
    }
}
```

However there are a fair few entities, and I'm not fond of using switch-case statements where a better solution might be present.

Is this considered to be the best practice, or are there better ways of doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem with all "I have unknown X" cases tends to be that at some point something has to know what X is (at least when strong typing is involved). Whether it's checked by library code or your code, something has to do it. Your code isn't best practice, it's "I had to do it like this". BTW why is the factory a `@Controller`?

Comment: Yeah I understand. My best hope was that spring might have this behaviour built into it to save some agro. The `@Controller` should have been `@Component`, the code was just a hasty example.

Comment: So what prevents you from going with `em.persist()`?

Comment: @Kayaman there's nothing preventing me from using the entity manager directly, I just didn't think of it. Would it be just sensible to `@Autowire` an `em` into each of the appropriate classes?

Comment: That's what I would do, but what do you mean "**each** of the appropriate classes"? The appropriate class would be the one that receives the objects parsed from XML and is responsible for saving them.

Comment: @Kayaman Apologies, you're right this should only be required in that single class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has already been given in the comments above, but I think an answer is more convenient:

```
@Autowire
private EntityManager em;

public persistEntity(Object entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
}
```